# Trouble connecting to phantomJs webdriver using python and selenium

Tags: python, linux, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to run a python script on a linux server which uses selenium and a phantomjs webdriver; however, I keep getting the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/ubuntu/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

Here is a simple test script that fails and generates this error:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/home/ubuntu/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs')
```

calling file on the path, returns:

```
file  /home/ubuntu/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
/home/ubuntu/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=d0f2a21ff9e0b82113a2095e7cbca7dceaba88fb, stripped
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this script up and running?  I've read over what appear to be similar stackoverflow questions and attempted to apply suggested solutions such as reinstalling phantom via npm and executing the script with sudo, but have had no luck.  If I can provide anymore info please let me know.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig
```

This solved my issue.

Comment: I tried this solution but I still get the same status code was: 127 error message.

Comment: @Eunito did you find solution? the same problem (((

Comment: @DanilaGanchar unfortunately not :(