# PhantomJS and Selenium: WebDriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

With selenium and python I've got

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/local/bin/phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

I already call the executeble_path in the script and the path is correct:

```
whereis phantomjs
phantomjs: /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
```

Here [Trouble connecting to phantomJs webdriver using python and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338609/trouble-connecting-to-phantomjs-webdriver-using-python-and-selenium) is said of installing libfontconfig, but I've got it already:

```
libfontconfig1 is already the newest version (2.11.94-0ubuntu2)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Same issue here. Currently investigating.

Comment: Look there are analogy situation [https://stackoverflow.com/a/43168960](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43168960)

Comment: Yes, but I have already libfontconfig installed

Answer (score 0):

You may want to down the binary file of chromedriver  and use it. When you are using it, make sure you use the absolute path.